# How can I build a Python script that executes a process from RNAup?

Tags: python, bash

I'm using RNAup Web Server in order to identify thermodynamic features between sequences. I have installed the specific program on my Mac, and now the execution in bash it's a shell command inside a specific path. ​
After that, it asks me the first sequence and after it asks me a list of sequences to compare to the first.

```
 %RNAup -b -d2 --noLP -c 'S' RNAup.out
 %ACTCTGTCGTAGCTCGTCTAGCTGA
 %ACCCTTGGCTACAACCTTGGGTTAA
```

These three lines gave me a thermodynamic result.
The problem is that I cannot execute this code on bash but I have to execute it on Python terminal, as a script and I don't know how to do it. I've never wrote a script that executes processes so I really don't have any idea. I talk to my relator that suggested me not to use:

```
os.system('RNAup -b -d2 --noLP -c 'S' RNAup.out')
```

but to use a different library, like 'Process'.
The question is:
How can I write a script that physically passes something from my file to this process?

Comment: I guess you're not following your spelling checker. Even if I follow the guess that `relator` means *reporter*, I don't know the role of the person you talked to. Do you use `script` for *program source code* in general? I'm used to see it where interpretation is expected rather than compilation, especially in *command languages&interpreters*. (XY problem:) There may be saner ways to use a web interface from a Python program than to use a CLI tool: does `RNAup Web Server` have a documented interface?  (Please put information *in the question* rather than in a comment to a comment.)

Comment: RNAup doesn't have an interface, it's a bash program. I need a script because even if I can execute it in bash, all of these have to be documented for my thesis..
The worlds my relator said to me were "It's convenient to do a python script from which invoke external executable"

Comment: (`worlds my relator said` - I can't seem to relate to *relator* - how about *advisor* or *supervisor*?)

Comment: You may be looking for [Python Generic Operating System Services](https://docs.python.org/3/library/allos.html), especially `os.exec*()`, `os.posix_spawn*()`, `os.fork*()`.

Comment: Please add to your question what `using RNAup Web Server` means: What *is* `RNAup Web Server`? How do *you* use it?

Comment: (To "web programmers", *web server/service* means HTTP interface. To shell users, *shell program* (especially *script*) means a program in the shell command language, not a binary executable habitually called from the shell for absence of a GUI (or lacking suitability thereof).)

Comment: (Your interlocutor may be referring to [Python's *Subprocess management*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system).)

Comment: @greybeard I use RNAup by calling a command into the shell, the program runs and I have to insert two strings separated by a new line. After that, It returns some values that I have to store somewhere.

Comment: `I have to insert two strings separated by a new line` if that means you typing, you definitely should look into [subprocess management](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=python+tutorial+subprocess+management&ia=web).